# Put Image into FCKEditor from Popup window

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to insert an image into CFKEditor edit area from pop-up window and I don't know how to do that.Got any ideas?
MY CFML Code-

```
 <cfform>
 <cftextarea id="textimg" skin="silver" toolbar="Basic" richtext="true" name="body"    required="true" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></cftextarea>
 </cfform>
```

MY Pop-up Window Code-

```
 <form action="insertimage.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="nil">
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>&nbsp;Insert image&nbsp;</strong></legend>
<br>
Choose a file:
    <input name="newimg" type=file size=30>
<br>
    <input type=submit value=Insert name="act">
    <input onClick="self.close()" type=reset value=Cancel>
</fieldset>
</form>

<span id=disp></span>

<cfif StructKeyExists(FORM,"act")>
    <cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="newimg" destination="#application.fpath#exe\images\" nameconflict="MAKEUNIQUE">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        selvalue= '<cfoutput><img src="images/#file.serverfile#" width=100 height=100" alt="#file.clientfile#"></cfoutput>';
        window.opener.document.getElementById('txtimg').insertAdjacentHTML("BeforeEnd", '<cfoutput><img src="images/#file.serverfile#" width=100 height=100 onClick="InsertImg(\'images/#file.serverfile#\')" alt="#file.clientfile#"></cfoutput>');
    -->
    </script>
</cfif>
```

It usually work for cftextarea but not work in cftextarea with richtext is true case.
how can I solve this?Help me....

Answer (score 0):

I usually use CFFM for those features.

http://www.opensourcecf.com/cffm/